# QScroller grabGesture disables double click

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I am developing an application in Qt for Windows 7 touch screen PC.

### Problem

I have `QTableWidget` where I want to use kinetic scrolling (`QScroller`) with double click (double touch) which selects and processes item from table. Without kinetic scrolling, my solution to connect slot to `QTableWidget` signal `itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidgetItem *)` was successfull. When I added this code

```
QScroller *sc = QScroller::scroller(tableWidget);

tableWidget->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
QScroller::ScrollerGestureType gesture = QScroller::TouchGesture;

sc->grabGesture(tableWidget, gesture);
```

my solution stops working. With mouse double clicks is everything OK, but touch double clicks stop working. When `scroller->grabGesture(tableWidget, gesture);` is commented, everything works except kinetic scrolling.

How can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this workaround

```
scroller->grabGesture(tableWidget, QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
```